# Probability distribution of expression containing random variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Two independent random variables $A$ and $B$ share the same probability distribution
$$p_{A}(x) = p_{B}(x) = \frac{1}{2^{x+1}} $$
where $x$ is a non negative integer.

N is a random variable given by:
$$N = 4 + 2A + 3B$$

What is the distribution of N? Is there a general method for generating a new probability distribution from an expression containing random variables with given distributions?

Comment: Presumably $A$ and $B$ can take non-negative integer values $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$, so $N \in \{4,6,7,8,9,10,\ldots \}$.  $N$ will not have a named distribution but you can find it if you know the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$ - perhaps they are independent

Comment: You can't know the distribution of $N$ without spelling out the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$. A common situation is having them independent.

Comment: @Henry  My notation might be off but yes A and B can take a value $x \in N$. They are variables that could represent how many heads you can get in a coinflip without getting any tails for example.

Comment: @Ian I added the information that A and B are indeed independent.

Comment: @Henry I want to clarify that my last comment used $N$ and refererad to the natural numbers which might have been a bit confusing. In either case you understood it correctly in your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that if you want to compute the distribution of a function of $A,B$, given that you have no the joint density, the only alternative is that you assume independence between A and B

Second, note that A an B have the following pmf

$$P(A=x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$$

where $X=0,1,2,3,...$

this is a Geometric distribution

to find the law of N you have to combine events of A and B

As @Henry alrady commented, the support of N is

$$N \in \{4,6,7,8,9,10,11,...\}$$

Thus

$$P(N=4)=P(A=0;B=0)=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$P(N=6)=P(A=1;B=0)=\frac{1}{8}$$

etc etc

---

at the end ouf your process (calculating the first 10 outcomes you will get the solution by induction finding that the support is

$$\{4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,...\}$$

with probabilities

$$\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32,}\frac{1}{32},\frac{1}{32},\frac{1}{32},\frac{1}{64},...\}$$

Comment: How would one create a general formula without having to explicitly state each case? Is this possible? Later we get things such as $P(N = 10) = P(A=3;B=0) + P(A=0;B=2) $ and the number of possible combinations grows quickly with large N.

Comment: @EmilJansson : I do not know how to answer  you, but in this case I see a repeating rule (by induction) so, for example to find out the probability of the outcome $X=48$ first observe that 48 is in the #44 position, correspondly at a probability of $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ and so on...

Comment: I think the probability for $N=10$ is $\frac3{32}$ not $\frac{1}{16}$.  Similarly I disagree with your values for $12,13,14,15$

Comment: @Henry : as usual,  you are right...

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed form for this case, but I suspect it could be ugly involving the three cube-roots of $2$ (two of them complex) and specific to this example.

So instead for an example of the more general case, consider the probability generating function of $A$ and $B$: $\dfrac{1}{2-x}$, Then $2A$ has  probability generating function $\dfrac{1}{2-x^2}$ and $3B$ has  probability generating function $\dfrac{1}{2-x^3}$ and the constant $4$ has generating function $x^4$.

If they are independent then $N=4+2A+3B$ has  probability generating function $$\dfrac{x^4}{(2-x^2)(2-x^3)} = \dfrac{x^4}{4-2x^2-2x^3+x^5}$$ and expanding this gives $$\frac14x^4+\frac18x^6+\frac18x^7+\frac1{16}x^8+\frac1{16}x^9+\frac3{32}x^{10}+\frac1{32}x^{11}+\frac3{64}x^{12}+\cdots$$ where the coefficients of $x^n$ gives the probability $\mathbb P(N=n)$.

We can turn this into a recurrence with $$\mathbb P(N=n)=\tfrac12\mathbb P(N=n-2)+\tfrac12\mathbb P(N=n-3)-\tfrac14\mathbb P(N=n-5)$$ starting with $\mathbb P(N=0)=\mathbb P(N=1)=\mathbb P(N=2)=\mathbb P(N=3)=0$ and $\mathbb P(N=4)=\frac14$.